# Django commit database changes later on command

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an eCommerce website that uses some form of verification as soon as a user upload/edits a product, once the product is updated the database property of the `Product` model `isApproved` is set to False, and if it's set to false the product won't show on the site because I set only approved products to be viewed. so how can I make it that when a user edits a product I can see the changes before committing it to the database? so that the previous version of the product is still live?

Comment: Please share the code, what you have tried till now.

Comment: i haven't tried anything, when the user updates their product `isApproved` gets set to false because I need to verify that he/she updated it without putting any compromising content, so this makes the product not display on the actual website till `isApproved` is set to true, so I want to show the previous content on the website as I validate the updated information

Comment: Give it a try first, if you earlier used to load products as ```Product.objects.all()```, just change it to ```Product.objects.filter(isApproved=True)```. Now only approved products would be shown.